# Calling SQL Server procedure to INSERT values for two more columns in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a single SQL Server stored procedure in which I  can input my own `c_id` and `COST` along with my previously created SQL Server stored procedure.

My tables are as follows:

- TB1: A (a_id (pk), a_name, a_description, a_qh)
- TB2: AC (ac_id (pk), a_id(fk), c_id(fk), ac_cost)
- TB3: C (c_id (pk), c_name)

My previously created procedure looks like following:

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AProduct (@name char(30), @description varchar(255)) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PCount INT
    DECLARE @vid as int
    DECLARE @cost as int
    SELECT @PCount = Count(A_ID) FROM A
        WHERE a_Name= @name
    IF @PCount=1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE A 
        SET @name=A_Name,@description=A_Description
        WHERE A_ID=1
    END
    Begin
     Update AC
     SET @C_id=C_ID,@cost=Cost
     WHERE AC_ID=1
    END
    Return SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

My dilemma is I am new to SQL Server stored procedures, and I am trying to insert my new 'c_id', and 'ac.cost' along with a_name and a_description. So, if you can guide me through explanation . That will be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. I have updated my previously created procedure.  To reflect that.Now, I was thinking I would just update my current table by using above "UPDATED CODE" . I was wondering it this could work .For something I want to achieve